# Should we move to close old, abandoned questions with not enough detail?

Tags: discussion, questions, close-reasons

By old, I mean about six months or older. By abandoned, I meant that people have asked for clarifications in the comments so that they can answer the question better but the OP hasn't responded in months. I was thinking of closing them under the **not a real question** justification.

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. **This question is
>   ambiguous, vague, incomplete,** overly broad, or rhetorical and **cannot
>   be reasonably answered in its current form.** For help clarifying this
>   question so that it can be reopened, see the FAQ.

---

Some examples:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19003/replacement-icons-on-arcmap-toolbar

[How to solve a Run-time error 91?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18657/how-to-solve-a-run-time-error-91)

---

Shall I go through with it or should I leave those questions alone?

Comment: @whuber I like this idea, needs to be done. However, is there a way, when I flag to close a question, to leave notes along with my flag? It would be nice to be able to put in a small note, something like "Abandoned by OP" to clarify why I think the question should be closed.

Comment: @Chad There is an "other" option you can use when flagging. It only gives you about 200 characters to explain, so you have to be brief!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I thoroughly agree, and would go even further: when the O.P. has been asked explicitly for clarification and has not provided it within a day (not counting weekends), I think it's fair to close the thread.

All rules have exceptions: sometimes a perceptive reader offers a helpful answer in the meantime and it is marked as accepted.  That can (and probably should) be viewed as a form of clarification of the question.  But overall the principle stands: the community should consider closing any thread that has been languishing for more than a day or two in a state of uncertainty about what the question really is.

Comment: I better get started then. Lots of old questions to examine :)

Comment: A week might be a little less agressive. "Weekend" is a timezone (and sometimes cultural / regional) dependent issue, so a few days grace might be reasonable.

Comment: @Brad My recommendation strikes a balance between the desire to keep questions open and active and the need to improve ill-formed questions as quickly as possible.  Such questions often get downvoted, which newer users can perceive as being unfriendly. If a request for clarification is made in a comment and there is not a quick response, we at least know the O.P. is not closely monitoring the question and therefore they should not be too concerned if it is closed while we are awaiting a response.

Comment: I agree with Brad, a day to answer is a little tight.

Comment: @Nigel Before voting to close I first check to see whether the O.P. has logged in after the request(s) for clarification were posted.  Then I allow a few more hours for them to respond.  If they have not, it's a fair presumption that they do not attach much importance to their question and/or have little intention of improving it, so I see no reason to wait any longer before taking appropriate action. Many (if not all) users can do this check, too: look at the O.P.'s profile to see when they were last logged in.

Comment: Sorry Whubber but I can think of many occasions when it just hasn't been possible for me to login for more than 24 hours. Life is like that sometimes.

Comment: You miss the point, @Nigel: I am saying that we can wait until several hours *after* you have logged in.

Comment: Apologies Whuber, I had missed that point. I agree that if the OP logs on, and is logged on for a couple of hours, then it is unacceptable to ignore comments designed to help them.