# Should this abandoned question be closed?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, close-reasons

[This question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/26434/753) was asked over a year ago and immediately abandoned by its author. It was never answered, but it was never that clear to begin with what the code does, what its purpose was, and any context about where it is supposed to run. The only activity it has had was some recent tag edits.

I would suggest closing it simply because it has been abandoned, but is that in the spirit of the site? What if someone else has the same question (unlikely... but...)?

This related question suggests we should: [Should we move to close old, abandoned questions with not enough detail?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1989/753)

And I am of the same opinion. Is there any reason we shouldn't? What is the correct close reason in this case, if there is one?

Comment: This question has a lot in common with [**Do we need new Reason to Close old Questions when Originator appears to have lost interest?**](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3002/do-we-need-new-reason-to-close-old-questions-when-originator-appears-to-have-los) so I am going to propose that it is a duplicate.

Comment: My advice is don't forget about down-voting! (see [Standard practice to close vague](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3094/standard-practice-to-close-valid-but-vague-questions-abandoned-by-asker). For the particular question you reference, I admit to being mystified as how it ever garnered 3 upvotes (at present reading).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just closed / put it on hold for being too unclear.

Answer (score 3):

I agree wholeheartedly with closure in such instances - particularly as we approach 5,000 Unanswered Questions.

This issue keeps coming up:

- [Do we need new Reason to Close old Questions when Originator appears to have lost interest?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3002/do-we-need-new-reason-to-close-old-questions-when-originator-appears-to-have-los)
- [Standard practice to close (valid, but vague) questions abandoned by asker?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3094/standard-practice-to-close-valid-but-vague-questions-abandoned-by-asker)
- [Should we move to close old, abandoned questions with not enough detail?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1989/should-we-move-to-close-old-abandoned-questions-with-not-enough-detail)
- [Should this abandoned question be closed?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3346/should-this-abandoned-question-be-closed) (this question)

I am in favour of a more "ruthless" approach to closing old questions which appear to have been abandoned by their askers, and our community, because it only needs an upvoted answer not the asker's acceptance to get them off the Unanswered list.